# objective-c freezes after sending to web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, soap

I have worked so hard to write an IPad app, it takes 3 photos and send them to a .net soap web service. It sends the photos properly, I can see them in my server. But the problem is when I click the send button, the button stays blue(clicked effect) and the app freezes.

I believe I am doing something wrong with the sending photos to webservice. I am doing all the releasing stuff too.

Please take a look at my code to tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
recordResults = FALSE;

datax = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(u1,0.6);
resultx = [datax base64Encoding];

datax2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(u2,0.6);
resultx2 = [datax2 base64Encoding];

datax3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(u3,0.6);
resultx3 = [datax3 base64Encoding];


NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope 
                            xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
                            xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
                            xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<SendData xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<containerId>%@</containerId>"
                         "<date_>%@</date_>"
                         "<image1>%@</image1>"
                         "<image2>%@</image2>"
                         "<image3>%@</image3>"
                         "<question1>%@</question1>"
                         "<question2>%@</question2>"
                         "<question3>%@</question3>"
                         "<question4>%@</question4>"
                         "<question5>%@</question5>"
                         "<question6>%@</question6>"
                         "<notes>%@</notes>"
                         "<transDate>%@</transDate>"
                         "<userId>%@</userId>"
                         "<macId>%@</macId>"
                         "<sFileID>%@</sFileID>"                             
                         "</SendData>"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n", @"33", @"2013-09-09", resultx ,
                              resultx2 ,resultx3 ,@"true" ,@"true", @"true", @"true" ,
                              @"true" , @"3", @"notes", @"2013-09-09", @"123",
                              @"mymacid", @"sfileid"];
NSLog(soapMessage);

_lbl_result.text = soapMessage;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.57/service1.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/SendData" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = 
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}

//[nameInput resignFirstResponder];
}

  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
 didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
  {
[webData setLength: 0];
   }
  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
[webData appendData:data];
  }
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
[connection release];
[webData release];
 }
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] 
                                            length:[webData length] 
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(theXML);
_lbl_result.text = theXML;

[theXML release];

[connection release];
[webData release];
   }
```

Comment: Could you paste the error message? Thanks

Comment: there is no error message, it does what it is supposed to do. it sends images to web service and that is perfect but the app freezes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're performing network code on the main thread (UI thread), so it will be locking up because you're giving it work, other than UI orientated work to do.

I would suggest the following method:

`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:]`

It should be a straight swap for your synchronous call, the block completionhandler will give you status

For example, with the following you would remove all your delegate call backs for NSURLConnection

Replace:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

with:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {  
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[[data bytes] length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
    NSLog(theXML);  
    _lbl_result.text = theXML;  
    [theXML release];    
}];
```

Comment: I am new to IOS. would you please tell me where to paste this

Comment: I replaced it but samthing happens

Answer (score 4):

You need to run your sever calls on a separate thread. the reason why its freezing is because you are running it on your UI thread. try using this.

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Run server call
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Run UI Updates
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you create request in main thread so your app is freez..you create your request in background thread and so loading icon for user ...for loading icon see https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: +1 for MBProgressHUD reference, handy project, really easy to use to.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to send the request asynchronously using the method: sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:

Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was sending the images to webservice in the main thread. I fixed that problem with the answer above by @user352891 . However, it didnt solve my problem completely.

Sending 3 photos from Ipad is a large data. unfortuantely, I was watching what I send to webservice and display the webservice object in a label and logs. and that s why it hangs. it waits for the response from the webservice which is hugeeeeee.

I commented all the logs and displaying to labels. and it worked